# viewholder and expandable listview

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, expandablelistview

I have a problem with implementing ViewHolder and expandable listview/getChildView together.
what I have is a list of players with profile pictures, about 20 person in different groupViews. By first load first 3 or 4 players become correct pictures. My problem is, that by scrolling up and down all player pictures(in all rows) are then filled up with pictures of first 3-4 players. So they repeat them. There are players without photos at all, so that database returns "no", and they should not be filled at all, but as I said, every row at the end has a photo , and this all are same pictures of first players.
So I guess something wrong with my ViewHolder or setTag, getTag, or something is wrong inside my AsyncTask

Update:
the thing is. If I do not use ViewHolder, which means I allways get a new "view" from inflater. than it works fine. If I starting use ViewHolder whith setTag()/getTag(). It doesn't work! :(

UPDATE:
I found interesting behavior. The only one place in my code where the player picture could be change is here:

```
            @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
             Log.d("RESULT:", player_sid + ", " + success.toString());
              if (success) { 
                  vh.player_pic.setImageBitmap(bm);
              }
             }
```

as you see I put logging there. lets say we have 5 elements, name_1, name_2... name_5. And name_1 and name_2 have pictures, and other not. And lets say 3 of elements would fit into the screen and for others you need to scroll. At the first load I see on the screen:

name_1  pic_1

name_2  pic_2

name_3  no_pic

-------------- out of screen

name_4  ?

name_5  ?

then, if I beginn to scroll I see in logs:
"RESULT:", "name_5, false" BUT!!!!! I see a row on the screen:

name_5 pic_1

how?? in logs I see that "result" is false, and no  vh.player_pic.setImageBitmap(bm) would be called. The player_sid is also correct. But I see a picture of the "name_1" player.....

here a full code:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();

    Player p = (Player) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_player_list, null);

        vh.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_player_name);

        vh.player_pic = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.card_player_face);

        view.setTag(vh);

    } 

    vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        vh.name.setText(p.getName());

    ImageTask it = new ImageTask(vh, p.getPlayer_sid(), context);
    it.execute();

    return view;
}


  private class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private ViewHolder vh;
    private String player_sid;
    private Context context;

    Bitmap bm;

    public ImageTask(ViewHolder vh, String player_sid, Context context) {
        this.vh = vh;
        this.player_sid = player_sid;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return loadPlayerImage(player_sid);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (success) {
            vh.player_pic.setImageBitmap(bm);
        } 
    }

    private boolean loadPlayerImage(final String player_sid) {

        DbAdapterAll dba = new DbAdapterAll(context);
        String imgstr = dba.headshotGetByPlayerId(player_sid);
        if (!imgstr.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            byte[] byteArray = Base64.decode(imgstr, Base64.DEFAULT);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                    byteArray.length);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}

    private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView player_pic;
    public TextView num;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView club;
    public ImageView club_pic;

}
```

Comment: instead of sending ViewHolder to ImageTask pass Imageview

Comment: ViewHolderI's benefits are not worth the time spent on it

Comment: passing Imageview directly or ViewHolder does not have any difference, the result is the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Do the following change hope this help you

```
 ImageTask it = new ImageTask(vh.player_pic, p.getPlayer_sid(), context);

    it.execute();

public ImageTask(ImageView vhs, String player_sid, Context context) {
        this.vhs = vhs;
        this.player_sid = player_sid;
        this.context = context;
    }

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (success) {
            vhs.setImageBitmap(bm);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't work. The result is the same. I don't think there is a difference what you pass to the task, imageview directly or the viewholder. the object reference should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageView is reused by the listView when you scroll.Try

```
  private class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private ViewHolder vh;
    private String player_sid;
    private Context context;

    Bitmap bm;

    public ImageTask(ViewHolder vh, String player_sid, Context context) {
        vh.player_pic.setTag(player_sid); // bind the player id to the imageView
        this.vh = vh;
        this.player_sid = player_sid;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return loadPlayerImage(player_sid);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (player_sid.equals(vh.player_pic.getTag())) { //if imageView is reused for another player,old task won't replace the image
          if (success) { 
              vh.player_pic.setImageBitmap(bm);
          } else {
              //set default picture here
          }
        }
    }

    private boolean loadPlayerImage(final String player_sid) {

        DbAdapterAll dba = new DbAdapterAll(context);
        String imgstr = dba.headshotGetByPlayerId(player_sid);
        if (!imgstr.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            byte[] byteArray = Base64.decode(imgstr, Base64.DEFAULT);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                    byteArray.length);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: the same:( A tried to log player_sid, and I see that all tasks are started with new "player_sid", so with correct one.. And its really randomly how player_pic is filled... any time different pictures appear. I assume something wrong with (ViewHolder)view.getTag()

Comment: or may be this is related that this is not a normal listview but expandable?

Comment: try set a empty or default image before the task.execute?

Comment: there is a default image inside the imageview(in xml). It is displayed by default, if no imageview.setImageDrawable is called.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The think was: I had an xml row with "name" and "image". And an image had some default drawable ic_no_pic.
What I was trying to do> to load an image from database, and if attempt fail, did nothing.
And that was wrong. You allways needs to do:

```
if(load_Image_Was_Success){
    viewHolder.image.setImageResource(SOME_IMAGE_HERE);
} else {
    viewHolder.image.setImageResource(DEFAULT_IMAGE);
}
```

if you do not do this **else** the listview loads a new view with **replaced** image by previous rows. So it could be image from the 1st row, as example.

Was difficult to understand. Thanks everybody for your help!